# C++ recursive_directory_iterator miss some files

Tags: c++, recursion, iterator, directory, c++17

I'm trying to get all files in directory through c++17 on my visual studio 2017 but I've just encountered  a really weird problem. If I specify directory like this I can get all files without any problem:

```
    for (auto& p : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator("C:\\Users\\r00t\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla")) {
    if (std::filesystem::is_regular_file(p.path())) {
            std::cout << p.path() << std::endl;
        }
}
```

But I need all file list on APPDATA, and I'm trying to get path with getenv() function and when using it "recursive_directory_iterator" function skipping files:

```
    for (auto& p : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(getenv("APPDATA"))) {
    if (std::filesystem::is_regular_file(p.path())) {
            std::cout << p.path() << std::endl;
        }
}
```

Is that because of using getenv() function? Some folders that skipping when using getenv;

```
Mozilla 
TeamWiever
NVIDIA
```

and so on ..

Btw, I'm using C++ last 5 days and definitely don't have any clue what causes for that behavior. Please help me, right now I'm stuck.

EDIT :

```
    for (auto& p : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(getenv("APPDATA"))) {
    std::string targetFolder = p.path().string();
    for (auto& targetFolderFiles : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(targetFolder)) {
        if (std::filesystem::is_regular_file(targetFolderFiles.path())) {
            std::cout << targetFolderFiles.path() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This is also not working, seems like i must put string into function like this:

```
recursive_directory_iterator("C:\\Users\\r00t\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla")
```

otherwise definitely not working, LOL ??

---

EDIT - PROBLEM FIXED

Using experimental library is working with C++14 compiler like as expected.

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>
```

Now i can able to get all files without problem.Seems like this is problem about C++17 and filesystem library .. 
Thanks for all support guys.

Comment: What "files" exactly is it skipping? You're skipping entries based on `is_regular_file()`. Are you sure the "files" that are getting skipped are regular files and not symbolic links or something else!?

Comment: _"Some folders that skipping when using getenv;"_ A directory probably doesn't count as a _regular file_ as you're using that.

Comment: What does `getenv()` return? I can return `nullptr` after all.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel, nope they are not.Because its working while im compile codes like that "recursive_directory_iterator("C:\\Users\\r00t\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla")"

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ all of them regular file i already try.

Comment: @Galik "C:\Users\r00t\AppData\Roaming" that what returns, i can get some files but not all of them.

Comment: Using C++ for 5 days and using C++17. There is hope for the world. Usually folk pick up C++ and get pointed at materials from decades gone by.

Comment: @user4581301, i hate long codes makes me confuse that's why im trying to use newest thing but as you can see stuck on this problem last 2day :(

Comment: What is the string returned by `getenv("APPDATA")` ?

Comment: @bruno "C:\\Users\\r00t\\AppData" seems like problem not about getenv i compile codes with C++14 and experimental library its worked.OP updated.

Answer (score 2):

`getenv()` returns a `char*` or `NULL`. `<filesystem>` is *probably* operating with `wchar_t*` strings since you are on Windows. Use `SHGetKnownFolderPath(...)` to query for where special folders are.

What happens when you run your program is probably that you hit some character that can't be displayed with your current locale ("C" if not set explicitly) so it sets your outstream in fail mode. You can however set your locale to UTF-16LE to remedy this. It works with /std:c++17 and the standard `<filesystem>` header:

```
#include <Shlobj.h> // SHGetKnownFolderPath
#include <clocale>  // std::setlocale 
#include <io.h>     // _setmode
#include <fcntl.h>  // _O_U16TEXT
```

[Code Page Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/code-page-identifiers)

```
const char CP_UTF_16LE[] = ".1200";
setlocale(LC_ALL, CP_UTF_16LE);
```

[_setmode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=vs-2017)

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
```

With that in place, the path you get from `SHGetKnownFolderPath` should work:

```
PWSTR the_path;
if(SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_RoamingAppData, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, &the_path) == S_OK) {
    for(auto& p : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(the_path)) {
        std::wcout << p.path() << L"\n";

        // you can also detect if the outstream is in fail mode: 
        if (std::wcout.fail()) {
            std::wcout.clear();  // ... and clear the fail mode
            std::wcout << L" (wcout was fail mode)\n";
        }
    }
    CoTaskMemFree(the_path);
}
```

You may also find the list of [Default Known Folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/knownfolderid) in Windows useful.

Comment: "your program is probably that you hit some character that can't be displayed" nope definitely not related with my app, im %100 sure all of them valid paths.I thought exact same thing before and tested some paths with only numbers(to make sure path is valid) etc.  idk why but just worked on experimental  library.

Comment: @EmilyJanson I'm sure they are valid paths. Mine are too :-) But the consoles locale is set to "C" per default. I don't know if the experimental filesystem lib also supports native encodings, but if it doesn't, that _could_ explain why it seems to work. However, if you create a file with some _special_ characters in its name (like `®®®.test`) it will probably not look too good. Setting UTF-16LE (and using `std::wcout` for all console output) will make it better (but not perfect) at displaying the filenames - and it'll work with the standard `<filesystem>`.

Comment: If you try your old version and look at the last file it printed, was it the same last fille as you got when you tried experimental? Also, when you use newer WinAPI functions, some of them only work with `wchar_t*`'s, not `char*`'s (like `SHGetKnownFolderPath`) so it's probably best to get used to that :-)

Comment: This filename actually caused an exception (_No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page_) when I tried streaming it to `std::cout` : `®™¡Hola!αβγ.test`. By first setting UTF-16LE and streaming to `std::wcout` - no problem.

Comment: Literally after days ago i finally get your answer and yes its fixed my problem, idk SHGetKnownFolderPath is necessary but i did not use.Thanks my first app is done and its c++17 ! hehe. Btw you need to add #include <Shlobj.h> for SHGetKnownFolderPath() function in C++ please edit answer

Comment: @EmilyJanson Glad it helped! I've added the missing header file to the answer now.