# std::cout.imbue() multiple call

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Compiler : Visual Studio 2019(C++20, latest)
I have a question about std::locale
Is it impossible to call std::cout.imbue multiple?
Why is it impossible?

When I ran below code.. I can see two of question mark(??) after second imbue function call..

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    auto loc = std::locale("de_DE.utf8");
    std::cout.imbue(loc);
    std::cout << "locale_name = " << std::cout.getloc().name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << 100.50 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::showbase << std::put_money(1050) << std::endl;

    std::cout.imbue(loc);   // no output below
    std::cout << "locale_name = " << std::cout.getloc().name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << 100.50 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::showbase << std::put_money(1050) << std::endl;
}
```

**Here is output**
locale_name = de_DE.utf8
100,5
10,50 ??

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this [on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e1ef65a767aed90), for whatever that's worth.

Comment: @Ted My edit was the same :( Shame you took away my suggested edit points! Think [the system did that though](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25439482)

Comment: The two question marks is there because it can't display the euro  € currency symbol.

Comment: @Ted OP says they get _no output_ the second time, which is clearly wrong. But then the OP also says they get `??` the first time. Not very clear question.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings No, it's not necessarily wrong. If the stream enters a failed state, it'll stop outputting. The cause could be the currency symbol.

Comment: @TedLyngmo:  Interesting thought, but streams don't care about encoding, only about bytes. It's the renderer (e.g. terminal/console) who has the responsibility of decoding those bytes into something visible.

Comment: (And I do recall that VS's output window doesn't do Unicode very well; at the very least, if not ASCII, it's probably expecting UTF-16)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Here's a [longer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53823931/7582247) to that. Wrong locale, output stream fails and stops. Note that I used `clear()` for the output to continue if it was in a failed state.

Comment: @Ted Hmm. Interesting.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes you are write.. it comes from my locale state("ko_KR"), I think. I got all of output when I changed locale to "ko_KR" .. Thanks very much. I got a good lesson today.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such restriction, and [the output for me](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e1ef65a767aed90) is:

```
locale_name = de_DE.utf8
100,5
10,50 €
locale_name = de_DE.utf8
100,5
10,50 €
```

Note that the Euro symbol may be replaced by weird stuff like `??` if your output terminal is not properly configured to show UTF-8 characters, or if that glyph is missing in your terminal's font.

For example, from memory, Visual Studio's output console either does not support Unicode or always decodes as UTF-16. One of the two. Probably the latter.

Besides that, if you get output different from the above, that would be an interesting standard library bug in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks you are right. My locale is "ko_KR" and I got a expected output after locale value to my locale("ko_KR") Thanks.