# Problem with printing wide character in c

Tags: c, unicode, widechar

Hello I want to print the letter 'å' which is 131 in extended ascii and as far as I can see has UTF-8 code 00E5 and 0x00E5 in UTF-16. However, in the code below the program prints 'Õ' which is not what I wanted. I do not know what I have done wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
int main(void) {

   wchar_t myChar = 0x00E5;

   wprintf(L"%lc", myChar);

}
```

Comment: FYI, UTF-8 for `å` is the two bytes `C3 A5`, not `00E5`.

Comment: Which OS? Which compiler? Cannot help without this information. Also please bear in mind that there is no such thing as "extended ASCII".

Comment: Note: now (after 2020) I would avoid to use `wchar_t` but for legacy applications. Just use char (and UTF-8). In any case, also wchar_t strings must be treated as black boxes (or with complex algorithms to handle surrogates (wchar_t often is UCS-2 not UTD-16), and combining characters. Also now UTF-8 is the most expected format for files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try using an UTF-16 character literal and also set the locale ([`setlocale`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale)) to `CP_UTF_16LE` if using MSVC or to the user-preferred locale if not.

```cpp
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <io.h>     // _setmode
#include <fcntl.h>  // _O_U16TEXT
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

void set_locale_mode() {
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    // Unicode UTF-16, little endian byte order (BMP of ISO 10646)
    const char *CP_UTF_16LE = ".1200";

    setlocale(LC_ALL, CP_UTF_16LE);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
#else
    // set the user-preferred locale
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
#endif
}

int main(void) {
    set_locale_mode();  // do this before any other output

    // UTF-16 character literal with unicode for `å`:
    wchar_t myChar = u'\u00E5';

    wprintf(L"%lc", myChar);
}
```

Tested in Windows 11 with VS2022

Comment: `wchar_t myChar = 0x00E5;` would be more portable and have identical behavior. The wide character syntax is not to blame, `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` does the job.

Comment: You might document the `setlocale()` call with `Set the locale to the user's default locale` instead of an obscure `do this before any other output`

Comment: @chqrlie  Hmm, I tested it in Linux too and both versions seems to work, but character encodings can be tricky so I don't claim this to be working everywhere. What portability issues with `u'\u00E5'` do you see?

Comment: it would take a perverse compiler to produce anything but `0x00E5` for `u'\u00E5'`, but I cannot speak for the various Microsoft platforms out there.

Comment: @chqrlie note and link about `setlocale` added.  _"... a perverse compiler to produce anything but `0x00E5` for `u'\u00E5'`"_ - :-) Perhaps. I prefer `\u` to clearly show intent and that it's a unicode that is intended.

Comment: Unicode character strings and constants `u'\u00E5'`are a C11 extension. I am not sure every platform supports them.  The `\u` escape sequence is c99, but the `u'` prefix is a more recent addition.

Comment: @chqrlie True. That could present a portability issue. MSVC supports C17 and gcc and clang has come far with C23 so at least the most common compilers are up to speed. I'd hate to be restricted to ANSI C for maximum portability Today :-)

Comment: Try U+20AC (EURO SIGN).  This doesn't work.

Comment: More specifically, `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` outputs in the console's encoding.  On US Windows, the default encoding is `cp437` which doesn't support the euro sign.  Western European Windows has a different default and might.  Use `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);`  to output correctly regardless of console encoding.  You can also change the default encoding to UTF-8 in the system settings, and then this answer should work for all Unicode characters sent to the console, but an appropriate font is needed for the characters used.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks Mark. I was on a Swedish computer so I forgot. :-) [Back in 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53823931/7582247), I found combining setting the locale _and_ mode working well so I added the same to this answer.

Comment: Why should we use UTF-16 instead of UTF-8?

Comment: @AlexanderJonsson I'm not suggesting you should, but you used `wchar_t`s and the unicode 0x00E5, which doesn't make sense for UTF-8.

Comment: If I were to use UTF-8 instead of UTF-16, how would that look? The UTF-8 code for å is 0xC3 0xA5, and I am not sure how to write it in the code?

Comment: @AlexanderJonsson A string, like `u8"\u00E5"` would be capable of storing it. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/deMhvaGPf). Note that `\u00E5` is still the same, but making it an `u8` string makes it store the proper bytes.

Comment: I seem to recall the `u` prefix forced the characters to UTF-16, which I now avoid like the plague. The `u8` prefix is intriguing, though. What is the purpose of it? I just tried out all the working compilers on [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Pjoa96x5s) and they already default to UTF-8 strings, even for something like `unsigned char foo = "\U0001F428";`. Is the u8 prefix for Microsoft's compiler? GodBolt kept telling me "MSVC does not support execution".

Comment: @hackerb9 You have the full list of string literal prefixes [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). The purpose of `u8`  is to create an UTF-8 character or string literal. If you use unicode code points, like `\u00E5`, the actual bytes stored will be different depending on what kind of string literal you are creating. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/3ersdEdY4)

Comment: Thank you, Ted. MSVC didn't give any output for your program, but other than that, it looks like using the u8 prefix is functionally equivalent to [not using any prefix](https://godbolt.org/z/KzeTv17fG) on all GodBolt compilers. Right?

Comment: @hackerb9 I'm not sure I understand. What MSVC version did you test it with? You know Compiler Explorer currently does not support executing programs compiled with MSVC, right?

Comment: Thank you, I suspected that. My question is: are there any compilers which behave differently for a string like `"foo"` versus `u8"foo"`. Certainly for all the ones in Compiler Explorer that I was able to test, the prefix seems to have no effect. Here's an example which hopefully shows what I mean: [\u1F639 is the same](https://godbolt.org/z/xEK74MqKe). I do not have a way to test MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, to output Unicode characters the console mode needs to be changed:

```c
#include<fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    // UTF-16 character literal with unicode for `å`:
    wchar_t myChar = 0x00E5;

    // Adding U+20AC EURO SIGN as well.
    wprintf(L"\u20ac%lc", myChar);
}
```

Output:

```
€å
```

Comment: Windows doesn't automatically set the mode of stdout when you use wprintf? Is it also missing the POSIX `fwide()` function?